# Scratch and win

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am a computer science student, in the fourth year of high school, I have to start a project: CREATE A GRATTA AND WIN.
How can I modify this part of code?
I have to make sure that the variable **card_surface** is an image and not a color, but I don't understand how to do it.

I tried to modify the  **card_surface** variable, assigning it an image but it doesn't work in this case.

then I just tried to create another **variable of type Image** that would take the place of **card_surface**, in this case the image is present but it does not become transparent

```
class DrawPad extends JComponent {
BufferedImage image;
BufferedImage card_surface;

Graphics2D graphics2D;
int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;
 public void clear() {
    image=null;          
    card_surface=null;
    repaint();
}


  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    String imagePath;
    int numero= Main.numero;
    if (image == null) {

        image = new BufferedImage(500, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        if(numero<=7) {
            imagePath = "HAI VINTO.PNG";
            File inFile = new File(imagePath);
            System.out.println("vinto");

            try{
                image = ImageIO.read(inFile);
            }catch(java.io.IOException e){System.out.println(e);}
        }
        else{
            imagePath = "HAI PERSO.PNG";
            File inFile = new File(imagePath);

            try{
                image = ImageIO.read(inFile);
            }catch(java.io.IOException e){System.out.println(e);}
        }

        graphics2D = image.createGraphics();

        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        repaint();
    }

    if (card_surface == null) {
        card_surface = new BufferedImage(500, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        graphics2D = (Graphics2D) card_surface.getGraphics();
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
        graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);

        repaint();
    }
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(card_surface, 0, 0, null);
    Image transpImg2 =TransformColorToTransparency(card_surface, new Color(0, 50, 77), new Color(200, 200, 255));
    BufferedImage resultImage2 = ImageToBufferedImage(transpImg2, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(resultImage2, 0, 0, null);
}
```

}

Comment: sorry gratta means scrat Scratch

Comment: Can't see where `card_surface` is declared.  You'll get better help if you provide a [mcve]

Comment: I edited it. I hope you can help me.

Comment: So, feedback - Don't maintain a reference to `Graphics2D` that you didn't create. Don't load images resources in `paintComponent`, `paintComponent` should operate as fast as possible and doing I/O is going to slow it down.  Don't call `repaint` in a paint pass, you're setting yourself up for some serious issues.

Comment: You already seem to know how to load images, so I'm kind of wondering what the issue is

Comment: the problem is that when I load the image it does not become transparent, this only happens if there is a color

Comment: Please take MadProgrammer's advice and try to reproduce your problem in a compete and self-contained example. I do not see a static main method in your example code, therefore I believe that it is probably not complete. A minimal example also would not contain the if(numero<=7) {...}else{...} to load different images based on conditions not important to the problem.

Comment: Don't delete posts that are going wrong. Instead [edit] them! If I have to issue comments twice (in this case taken care of by @MadProgrammer) it's an automatic down-vote. Plus what was wrong with the earlier post is also wrong with this one. Voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) and [Ludwig Schulze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4110406/ludwig-schulze), a simplified and working version of your code is very helpful for all the enthusiastic people here at Stack Overflow who want to help you. In an attempt to help you to create a so-called [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I've taken part of your code (that hopefully contains your issue) and added a simple `Main` class (so we can execute the code). You could compare this code to your project and/or use this code as a starting point.

The `Main` class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        new Main().createGuiAndLaunch();
    }

    private void createGuiAndLaunch() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);

        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        // Image from https://ya-webdesign.com/transparent250_/52-playing-cards-png.png
        String imagePath = "input/q60141219/52-playing-cards-png-transparent.png";
        frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleDrawPad(imagePath));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

A `SimpleDrawPad` class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class SimpleDrawPad extends JComponent {
    private BufferedImage image;

    public SimpleDrawPad(String imagePath) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

The "playing-card-6-clubs-transparent.png" image used in the code:

[image: playing card 6 clubs transparent]

In the screenshot below, the yellow background color is visible, so the `SimpleDrawPad` component is transparent:

[image: screenshot with transparent component]

Comment: Thanks for the answering.
I have to do a similar thing but a little different there are two images one above and one below that above must become transparent to show the one below.

Comment: Can you change the code in your question to a simplified and working version (similar to the one in my answer) that has the issue? If you include the two images, we can try to figure out what's happening. (The problem might be caused by the images.)